# criando um bot de votação em python

Tags: python

```
import requests

dados = {"action": "polls",
         "view":"process",
         "poll_id":"2",
         "poll_2":"6",
          "poll_2_nonce":"e29cc82a53"}

url = "http://soulegal.byethost7.com/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

requests.post(url, data=dados)
```

URL : http://soulegal.byethost7.com/wp/2016/07/28/pesquisa-eu-sou-legal

O plugin wordpress é WP-Polls.

O site é meu. Só consigo votar manualmente quantas vezes eu quiser mas o código não funciona (não dá nenhum erro mas não vota).
Alguém ajuda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com requests não vai dar porque não processa Javascript, se fizer:

```
import requests

req = requests.get("http://soulegal.byethost7.com/wp/2016/07/28/pesquisa-eu-sou-legal/")
print(req.status_code)
print(req.text)
```

Consegue ver o que imprime:

> 200
>
> ...This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support...

Isto diz-nos basicamente que o pedido (*request*) foi bem sucedido (código 200) mas que precisamos de um browser (navegador), ou algo que processe javascript implícitamente (desconheço). No entanto bons programadores desenvolveram um modulo que se chama [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) que faz isto tudo automáticamente (abrir o browser, selecionar, submeter o formulário, ect...). E pussui uma [documentação](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) bem estruturada:

Para votar em diversas opções:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
opts = ['poll-answer-6', 'poll-answer-7', 'poll-answer-8'] # id das opcoes em que deseja votar

for i in opts:
    driver.get("http://soulegal.byethost7.com/wp/2016/07/28/pesquisa-eu-sou-legal/?ckattempt=1")
    opt = driver.find_element_by_id(i) # selecionamos o elemento com id
    opt.click()
    btn_submit = driver.find_element_by_name('vote') # selecionamos o elemento que como name tem 'vote', o nosso botao
    btn_submit.click()
    print('Votou em {}'.format(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('label[for="' +i+ '"]').text))
```

Para selecionar a mesma opção diversas vezes, neste caso 5 vezes:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
opt = 'poll-answer-7' # id opcao em que deseja votar
votos = 5

for i in range(votos):
    driver.get("http://soulegal.byethost7.com/wp/2016/07/28/pesquisa-eu-sou-legal/?ckattempt=1")
    opt_ele = driver.find_element_by_id(opt)
    opt_ele.click()
    btn_submit = driver.find_element_by_name('vote')
    btn_submit.click()

opt_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('label[for="' +opt+ '"]').text
print('Votou em {} {} vezes'.format(opt_text, votos))
```

Comment: Consegui rodar o código no Kali Linux. Funcionou. Muito obrigado. Só resta eu entender o código.

Comment: Se quiser abrimos uma conversa no chat e eu explico-lhe passinho a passinho. Ainda bem que resultou @EdMail

Comment: Se puder, eu agradeço!

Answer (score 3):

Existem raras excepções em que não é possível preencher campos de um formulário utilizando um simulador de browser como o selenium.

Nesses casos, e se estiveres a utilizar python 3 podes utilizar como alternativa de último recurso um modulo que simula as entradas do rato e teclado do computador chamado '[PyAutoGUI](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)'.

Para o instalar em linux basta fazeres o seguinte na linha de comandos:

```
pip3 install python3-xlib
sudo apt-get install scrot
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
pip3 install pyautogui
```

Um exemplo da sua utilização, para o teu caso, seria algo deste género:

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(2)

# funcao para ir, clicar e esperar
def clicar(link, tempo_mov=0.5):
    area = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(link)
    centro_area = pyautogui.center(area)
    pyautogui.moveTo(centro_area, duration=tempo_mov)
    pyautogui.click(centro_area)

while True:
    clicar('./opcao.png')
    clicar('./botao_voto.png')
    clicar('./refescar.png')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Rui porquê o uso `time.sleep(2)`?

Comment: Para espera que o utilizador selecione manualmente o browser na página de votações.

Comment: Obrigado pelo código. Muito útil!

Comment: @EdMail De nada, sempre às ordens.

Answer (score 2):

Verifique o retorno da requisição. Para ter dado certo, o `status_code` precisa ser 200:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=dados)
print(response)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Vou verificar e retorno! Obrigado.

Comment: A saída é  <Response [200]>
200

Comment: `print(response.text)` retorna o que?

Comment: This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>

Comment: É, então [siga a resposta do Miguel](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143334/2999), que já tem um bom roteiro de resolução.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua contribuição!