# Como criar um port scanner TCP usando o método SYN (TCP SYN)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#####################################
# Portscan TCP         #
# #
#####################################
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket

ip = input("Digite o IP ou endereco: ")

ports = []
count = 0

while count < 10:
    ports.append(int(input("Digite a porta: ")))
    count += 1


for port in ports:
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.settimeout(0.05)
    code = client.connect_ex((ip, port)) #conecta e traz a msg de erro
#Like connect(address), but return an error indicator instead of raising an exception for errors
    if code == 0: #0 = Success
        print (str(port) + " -> Porta aberta")
    else:
        print (str(port) + " -> Porta fechada")

print ("Scan Finalizado")
```

O código acima é um TCP Scanning. Como posso transformá-lo em um TCP SYN scanning?

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://gist.github.com/fffaraz/57144833c6ef8bd9d453

Comment: Ainda estou tentando!

Comment: Conseguiu? Paul sinceramente acho que devia aprender a programar nesta área gradualmente, começando em coisas mais simples (ex: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143321/criando-um-bot-de-vota%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-python/143334#143334, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145883/como-pegar-as-manchetes-das-olimp%c3%adadas-no-site-da-cnn-com-python-usando-beautifu/145887#145887, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142790/login-no-facebook-com-python) acho que vai achar interessante estes links, são desta área e são coisas que pode escalar e fazer coisas mais complexas

Comment: Ainda não consegui!

Comment: Deu uma olhadela nos links? Correu o código? Sabe como mover a discussão para o chat?

Comment: Eu acho que não tenho reputação para isso ainda!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44203/discussion-between-miguel-and-paul-sigonoso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul, um pacote TCP SYN (Synchronize) necessita de um processo chamado aperto de mãos (Handshaking) em três partes. São elas:

1) Envio de um pacote inicial (SYN) do cliente para o servidor

2) Envio de um pacote de reconhecimento de sincronização por parte do servidor ao cliente (SYN-ACK - Synchronize Acknowledge)

3) O final do aperto de mãos em três partes, enviado pelo cliente ao servidor  ou mensagem de reconhecimento (ACK - Acknowledge).

Como o protocolo TCP possui diversos sub-protocolos como por exemplo o HTTP este aperto de mãos varia muito e para implementar isto é necessário não só conhecimento de programação, mas conhecimento do protocolo ao qual está sendo feito o aperto de mãos.

Portanto sugiro que estude mais sobre a troca de pacotes SYN e sobre os protocolos que deseja sincronizar (ou estabelecer conexão - ou verificar portas).

**Editado:**
Conforme havia prometido segue um exemplo de comunicação com autenticação em 3 partes implementando somente a idéia, mas nenhum protocolo específico.

Quanto ao protocolo vou me abster do exemplo pois são inúmeras possibilidades e provavelmente um exemplo qualquer não servirá ao autor da pergunta, já que o mesmo não especificou nenhum.

Segue código do servidor e do cliente. Para testar execute na mesma máquina primeiramente o servidor e logo após uma instancia do cliente.

Código Servidor:
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
import socket
import thread

class ServidorTcp:

    def __init__(self, host, porta):
        self.TAMANHO_BUFFER = 1024
        self.socket_servidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket_servidor.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket_servidor.bind((host, porta))

    def escutar(self):
        self.socket_servidor.listen(5)
        print("Aguardando conexoes")

        while 1:
            (cliente, endereco) = self.socket_servidor.accept()
            print("Cliente conectado: " + endereco[0])

            thread_cliente = thread.start_new_thread(self.sincronizar, (cliente, endereco))

    def sincronizar(self, cliente, endereco):
        retorno = cliente.recv(self.TAMANHO_BUFFER)

        if(retorno == "SYN"):
            cliente.send("SYN-ACK")

            retorno = cliente.recv(self.TAMANHO_BUFFER)

            if(retorno == "ACK"):
                print("Sincronizado com o cliente remoto.")

        cliente.close()

#executar o server.
servidor = ServidorTcp('localhost', 7171)
servidor.escutar()
```

Código Cliente:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import socket

class ClienteTcp:

    def __init__(self):
        self.TAMANHO_BUFFER = 1024
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def conectar(self, host, porta):
        print("Conectando a " + host + ":" + str(porta) + "...")
        self.socket.connect((host, porta))

    def sincronizar(self):
        self.socket.send("SYN")
        retorno = self.socket.recv(self.TAMANHO_BUFFER)

        autenticado = False

        if retorno == "SYN-ACK":
            self.socket.send("ACK")

            #Conexao efetuada com sucesso.
            autenticado = True

        return autenticado

    def enviar(self, mensagem):
        self.socket.send(mensagem)

    def fechar(self):
        self.socket.close()

#executar o cliente.
cliente = ClienteTcp()
cliente.conectar('localhost', 7171)

if cliente.sincronizar():
    #Agora sei com quem estou me comunicando e a conversa pode iniciar entre as pontas.
    print("Sincronizado com o servidor remoto.")
else:
    print("Nao foi possivel estabelecer o sincronismo com o servidor remoto.")
```

Espero que minha resposta tenha sido útil.

Comment: poderia mostrar um exemplo simples em python? Gostaria de aprender. Só conseguir fazer o TCP "normal" @Bruno Bermann

Comment: Paul, não sou especialista em Python, especificamente. A noite terei o tempo para te dar esta resposta de maneira mais completa.

Comment: @ Bruno Bermann, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @Bruno Bermann, poderia mostrar uma implementação simples em python?

Comment: Paul Sigonoso e @Ed-S, conforme prometido segue meu exemplo em Python. Desculpe qualquer coisa mas não é uma linguagem que eu tenha domínio.

Comment: @Bruno Bermann, muito obrigado. Estou tentando aprender a programar. Foi muito útil o seu código.

Comment: @BrunoBermann, desculpe a ignorância. Não entendi: "Quanto ao protocolo vou me abster do exemplo pois são inúmeras possibilidades e provavelmente um exemplo qualquer não servirá ao autor da pergunta, já que o mesmo não especificou nenhum."

Comment: @EdS, os protocolos são padrões de troca de mensagens estabelecidos entre as pontas (cliente e servidor) os quais indicam como deve ser a comunicação. Por exemplo, definem que critérios devem ser seguidos para autenticar como um cliente válido ou mesmo por exemplo o protocolo HTTP (muito usado na web, junto com o HTTPS) estabelece um cabeçalho de mensagens e diversos parâmetros para este cabeçalho para que servidor e cliente se "entendam" na hora de conversar entre si. Para mais detalhes, leia: https://nandovieira.com.br/entendendo-um-pouco-mais-sobre-o-protocolo-http

Comment: @Bruno Bermann, muito obrigado!